# Uniqueness of hamiltonian cycle

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Let G be a graph on $n$ vertices, where $n \geq 8$ and with minimum degree at least $n/2$. Does $G$ have at least 2 distinct Hamilton cycles? (Two Hamilton cycles are said to be distinct if they differ in at least 1 edge).

I think this statement is true. I thought I could prove it using a maximal counterexample, where adding 1 edge would create a second Hamilton cicle and then follow the proof of Ore's theorem. However, that did not work out. Does anybody have an idea how to proof or refute this statement?

Comment: I think the clique with $8$ vertices is a pretty obvious counter-example or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: The clique with 8 vertices has 2 distinct hamiltonian cycles (only 1 edge has to be different!) and satisfies the minimum degree requirement. A counter-example must be a graph having only 1 Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: Oh I understand now. I thought your were trying to prove the uniqueness but you are actually trying to prove non-uniqueness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be shown using the [Bondy–Chvátal theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path#Bondy%E2%80%93Chv%C3%A1tal_theorem), which states that a graph $G$ is Hamiltonian if and only if $G + uv$ is Hamiltonian, where $u,v$ are nonadjacent vertices of $G$ with $d(u) + d(v) \geq n$.

To see this, take a Hamiltonian cycle $C$ of $G$ (guaranteed to exist by Dirac's theorem or its generalizations) and an edge $uv \in C$. We want to show that $G - uv$ is Hamiltonian. Now the Bondy-Chvátal theorem allows us to add every edge $xy$ with $x,y \notin \{u,v\}$ to $G-uv$, so that $G-\{u,v\}$ becomes a complete graph. But then the same theorem allows us to add all edges of the form $ux$ and $vx$ for $x \notin \{u,v\}$, and finally to add $uv$ back into the graph. In the end, we are left with a complete graph, which is, of course, Hamiltonian.

In fact, what we have shown is that $G-e$ is Hamiltonian for any edge $e$. You can use the same argument to show that you can leave about $n/4 - 1$ edges (I didn't check the precise number) and thus find that many different Hamiltonian cycles.

Comment: That's a nice solution. Now I even understand where the $n \geq 8$ comes from. Thank you very much!!